# How to accelerate duplicate closure of unpopular questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

Recently, I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541492/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-xcode-to-move-cursor-to-the-first-character-of-t) via other flag with the intention of having it insta-closed for duplicate. Given the status of the close vote queue, I don't really know when the question would be reviewed to be closed, so I decided to do this.

If you are wondering, my message was *rendered* as:

> Dup of [stackoverflow.com/questions/5241092/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241092/move-to-beginning-of-text-in-xcode). Author also commented so.

The flag was rejected and no action was taken.

I am aware this is abuse of the system. I am a veteran flagger and I have privilege to cast close vote for a long time. *So the rejection is justified - I have no complaint*.

However, the comment of the author and a quick read through the 2 questions would tell that the 2 questions are actually about the same problem.

So I have 2 questions here:

- Is it possible for diamond moderator to take action on such flags in the future? (take action != marking flag as helpful)
- How should I get such questions to be closed as duplicate faster?

Comment: Advertise the issue in chat.  You can usually find multiple users with enough rep to close.  You might even find a mod there to do it.

Comment: You can also make sure the OP knows he can cast his own vote if he has 250 rep.  It won't be binding, but will help get the process started.

Comment: The only problem might be that users in chat often run out of votes.

Comment: Moreover, this specific question isn't a _programming question_.  It's pertaining to an IDE.  It should be off-topic anyways.

Comment: @devnull: A tool related to programming is on topic on SO.